# Change Response from HTTP Request sent by a program

Tags: networking, http-headers, xmlhttprequest, fiddler, packet-sniffers

I have a program that activate an chip for racing results. (Its just a piece of hardware).
I watch with Fiddler (Sniffing program) the in and outgoing traffic from my pc when I connect the chip with my computer.

The program sends the following HTTP Request:

```
POST http://example.com/index.php HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 185
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Host: example.com
Pragma: no-cache
User-Agent: SomeProgram 1.2.3

Data==%0D%0AAjlFNEEw-SOMELONGSECRETKEY-RGAw%3D%3D%0D%0A
```

I receive the following response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<message type="3" result="1" txid="someid" activationdate="" availablecredits="732" firstname="John" lastname="Doe" email="JohnDoe@outlook.com" phonenumber="00123445" notification_email="1" notification_text="1"/>
```

Is it possible to edit the response so that when the programs check for the `availablecredits` variable, he get the value `9999` instead of `732`.

Im working on a Windows 8 laptop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely - Fiddler allows you to [**modify requests and responses**](http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/KnowledgeBase/FiddlerScript/ModifyRequestOrResponse) by [**adding rules to FiddlerScript**](http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/Extend-Fiddler/AddRules). Citing Fiddler documentation:

> To make custom changes to web requests and responses, use
>   FiddlerScript to add rules to Fiddler's OnBeforeRequest or
>   OnBeforeResponse function. Which function is appropriate depends on
>   the objects your code uses: OnBeforeRequest is called before each
>   request, and **OnBeforeResponse is called before each response**.

So, all you have to do is to add to **OnBeforeResponse** the logic for replacing the `availablecredits` attribute value with any value you desire.